# Kubernetes ingress not working on redirect on some path like "/myapp", but only working for "/"

Tags: kubernetes, docker-ingress

I have a container running on url like http://localhost:8000/ps/app/ui/?pid=201. The container is deployed on kubernetes and exposed to a service as "ps-app-ui:8000"
I want to create an ingress which can be accessible from outside. Ingress template is like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ps-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /myapp/
        backend:
          serviceName: ps-app-ui
          servicePort: 8000
```

The problem is its not working with this ingress. I also tried adding "ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /" but had no success. Can anyone help me to get my application accessible via "http://INGRESS-IP/myapp/ps/app/ui/?pid=201"

Will be really grateful.

Comment: Add an asterisk after `/myapp/`: `/myapp/*`

Comment: Is this... Minikube?

Comment: actually after ingress its a problem of absolute and relative path. my application expect url to be  http://localhost:8000/ps/app/ui/?pid=201 but after ingressurl become  http://localhost:8000/myapp/ps/app/ui/?pid=201
Which is failing it. @NorbertvanNobelen

Comment: @ShahzebKhan was there any resolution to this?

Comment: Exactly the issue that I bumped into. Can you pls share how u resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

Ingress version 0.22.0 or higher has changed the way how rewrite-target works.
You'll need to regex-match the path and add it to the rewrite-target.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
...
...
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

Refer to changelog [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases).
How to article [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking

```
- path: /myapp/
```

matches your app at `http://myapp/myapp/`

So if I have a definition:

```
  - host: app.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /myapp
```

This would be `http://app.example.com/myapp`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `http://myapp/ps/app/ui/?pid=201` you need to:

- make sure that your operating system translates `myapp` to a IP address where your ingress controller is listening
- add the `host` `myapp` to the ingress
- you can leave the path empty (assuming that your application is handling the complete `/ps/app/ui/?pid=201` path)

This results in

```
rules:
  - host: myapp
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ps-app-ui
          servicePort: 8000
```

This ingress will forward all traffic to the host `myapp` to your service

Comment: What i exactly want is to get my application working on http://<IPaddress>/myapp/ps/app/ui/?pid=201.
Application iteself is served on path /ps/app/ui/?pid=201
But problem is using ingress add this myapp path to applications path and make things ambigious .
The path / (empty) works fine but adding any string make it stop working

Comment: ok, I see you edited your question...
in that case: try without host, but set `/myapp` (without trailing slash) as path. And your application needs to listen on the `/myapp` part too, because as far as I know the that part won't be removed from the request!

Comment: I just found out that you can influence that behaviour of keeping the path, by adding some metadata to the ingress:

    ```apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
        ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /```
see https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/examples/rewrite/nginx